# How Can I Run a cross-module TestNG XML suite in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, testng

I'm trying to run a test suite that includes all of my unit tests across all of the (sub)modules of my project. In eclipse, this was done by simply running the xml test suite from the root of the project. If I try this in IDEA, I get a bunch of different errors depending on how I set up my Run Configuration.

Running my Suite as "In whole project", I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdv.config.name' in string value "${jdv.config.name}"
```

Otherwise, TestNG's main class simply can't be found.

This persists even when I provide the project's application.properties file (where the aforementioned property is stored) in the Properties file field under the Parameters tab.

Comment: Please [file a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.